# MVC Razor Editor Template for ContentEditable DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Being a little thick today. I need to create a MVC Editor Template that will use a DIV with `conteneditable="true"` and use the existing values. Tried a few approaches but dont appear to get the value in the div or for the value to update in the model. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

```
<div contenteditable="true" 
    id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty)" 
    name="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty)">
        @ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"for the value to update in the model"_? Are you expecting this to post back to a controller method?

Comment: So what's your model?

Answer (score 3):

A traditional browser submit (non ajax) will not submit the contents of a div. In fact the name attribute is not even valid on the div element to begin with.

You have a few options

1. Change the div to be an input element (You can style it so it doesn't look like an input box)
2. Use JavaScript to add the contents of the div to a hidden input before submitting the form.
3. Use AJAX to submit the form and select the data you need.